# What is the expectation and sample mean of a random set?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

Normally, when I think of a random element $X$ I think of it as being a random variable, or a random vector, or a stochastic process.

Say I have a random element $X$ which instead of being a real value is actually a fixed-cardinality set of real (or perhaps discrete) values, such as:

$$\{1.2, 3.4, 4.5 \}$$
$$\{7.8, 7.7, 6.5\}$$
$$\{10.2,4.5,400.2 \}$$

Is it possible or does it make sense to talk about the expected random set? Does it make sense to talk about higher moments? Practically, If I have observed $n$ i.i.d. sample sets, is it possible to talk about the sample mean of $X$, and other sample moments?

Assume here I don't know how the individual elements interact or what randomness generated them, but I only care about analyzing the set as a whole.

Comment: How much measure theory do you know?

Comment: Are they really fixed-cardinality sets or are they tuples/sequences? That is, are (1,2,3) and (2,1,3) the same or two different values? Is (2,2,2) allowed?

Comment: @Rahul good catch. Order doesn’t matter but repeated values are allowed. So I suppose we are dealing with multisets?

Comment: @XanderHenderson next to nothing