# Variance of Value in Monte Carlo Estimation of Shannon Entropy.

Tags: entropy, monte-carlo

The [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of a source $X$ (in bits) is defined as:-

$$ H(X) = -\sum_{x \in X}  {p(x) \log_2 p(x)}  $$

Following principles in [Variance of Area and Average Estimators in Monte Carlo Estimation of Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518748/394771) and [Having an empirical chart, what is the probability that the mean of a 99,000 sized set of bytes is $\le 127$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718083/394771) ,is it possible to determine the variance of $H(X)$ for any $X$?